# How to sort exported Firebase data on BigQuery without resource exceeding?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I use Firebase Analytics and export data to BigQuery. Now I'd like to filter data and sort them by timestamp.
I wrote this query:

```
SELECT event_timestamp, event_name, event_params, user_id,
user_pseudo_id, user_properties, STRUCT(device.category,
device.time_zone_offset_seconds, device.is_limited_ad_tracking) device,
platform FROM `myTable` ORDER BY event_timestamp;
```

But this results `Error: Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory. Sort operator used for ORDER BY used too much memory..`. I think the data is too much to put on BigQuery's memory.

The reason why I have to sort data is that I'd like to download the data and parse them in my on-premises application in the ascending order of timestamp. And if I change the sorting role to my application, it must take a lot of time.

I don't know fully about the feature of Google Cloud Platform. Is there any good way to sort huge data on GCP?

Comment: read [Managing Query Outputs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-output)

Comment: also, provide more info on size of output (rows) and what time (event_timestamp) period is covered  - is it days or hours?